# Recovery action for reserved kernel page: Failed

Tags: kernel

In a new install of Ubuntu 14.04.4 server, the kernel version is `4.2.0-27-generic`, there are the following entries in the syslog file.

```
MCE:0x10de:reserved kernel page still referenced by 1 users
MCE:0x10de:recovery action for reserved kernel page:Failed
MCE:0x10a1:already hardware poisoned
```

What do the entries mean? What does "already hardware poisoned" mean? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The processor is responding to a Machine Check Exception (MCE) on a page of memory. An MCE is hardware error and may be one of the following:

1) A system bus error (data error between the processor and the motherboard).

2) Memory error: a parity check detected a memory error.

3) Processor cache errors.

In your case, I suspect a memory parity check failure occurred and the kernel attempted to use the error correction code (ECC) to try to fix this, but there were too many bits corrupted so it could not.

The first kernel message is informing you that the corrupt page of memory is a page used by the kernel itself and is being shared/used by just 1 user.

The second kernel message is informing you that the page error could not be restored/fixed.

The final kernel message refers to the fact that hardware detected the memory error, the page was tagged as needing fixing "aka poisoned" and later on when the page has been read the MCE occurred and it repored the fact that the page had been tagged as poisoned.  This is a lazy operation because sometimes a page can become corrupt but it is then later written to so it is never read, so there is no need to fix it up.

Since this is a hardware error it may be due to physical issues, or maybe just a random bit flips caused by cosmic rays. If it occurs frequently, check that the memory is seated properly.